# figure out the structure difference of 2 urls in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Given the two URLs below, I need to be able to tell which structure the url is in (either url1 structure or url2 structure) and then parse out both random strings.  The domain name will be different each time so I can't hardcode in any specific domain name

url1 is in the form of `domainname.com/q/{random-6-character-alphanumeric-string}?arg1=something&arg2=something`

url2 is in the form of `domainname.com/q/{random-6-character-alphanumeric-string}/{random-3-character-alphanumeric-string}?arg1=something&arg2=something`

So for example, let's say:

```
url1 = mydomain.com/q/abc1de?arg1=something&arg2=something
url2 = mydomain.com/q/abc1de/b78?arg1=something&arg2=something
```

I tried just parsing `url1` and was able to figure out `parsedText1 = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0]`

The problem is this does not work for `url2` and I can't figure out how to write the code to distinguish between the two structures. How do I figure out which structure the url is in and then parse out the random strings accordingly?

Comment: Why not use [`new URL(url1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL) rather than trying to parse them yourself? (You will need to add a protocol first)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using [`URL.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) works for you?

```js
const a = new URL(`http://domainname.com/q/a2qwer?something=1&anything=2`);
const b = new URL(`http://domainname.com/q/a2qwer/re2?something=1&anything=2`);
console.log(a.pathname);
console.log(b.pathname);
```